# How to Autowire property in spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

I am trying to Autowire the field variables into the class by adding a property in my the bean configuration. so that when the spring gets instantiate the strings with value in properties.

my spring configuration file is as

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="authentication" class="com.quicut.model.authenticationModel">
    <property name="dbURL" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/quicut" />
    <property name="userN" value="user1" />
    <property name="userP" value="password" />
    <property name="JDBC_DRIVER" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
</bean>
```

the class that i created a bean for has the following fields which i want their values to be assigned by spring when instantiated.

```
public class authenticationModel {


    private String dbURL;
    private  String userN;
    private  String userP;
    private String JDBC_DRIVER;
```

the class which requires the dependency is as follows;

```
public class login extends HttpServlet {
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="authentication")
authenticationModel aModel;
```

i'm quite new to spring so i don't know what i am doing wrong or missing.

Comment: 1. You're not respecting the Java naming conventions; 2. You don't think error messages and stack traces are useful to know what the error is. My guess is that you're getting a NullPointerException, because a servlet is not a Spring component, and Spring thus can't autowire their properties. Use Spring MVC. And don't use Spring 2.5, which is obsolete for years and years.

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, you can name your classes with an initial capital letter, for example, instead of authenticationModel name it as AuthenticationModel.

Now, if you want to autowire spring beans in a particular Java class, you need to mark that class as a @Controller or @Service bean type. Only spring beans can autowire other beans.

In your case, your Login class is not marked as a particular spring bean, so you probably need to use one of the previous annotations.

For example:

```
@Service
public class LoginService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="authentication")
    AuthenticationModel aModel;
}
```